# Complex ActiveRecord query comparing datetime through many to many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, activerecord

So the objective of my query:

*Fetch all of a single user's clients that have not had a meeting since 30 days ago.*

A `Client has_many :meetings, through: :contacts` although contacts isn't very relevant here.

My query is as follows:

```
user.clients.where(is_dormant: false).joins(:meetings).distinct.where('meetings.actual_start_datetime <= ?', 30.days.ago).where.not('meetings.actual_start_datetime > ?', 30.days.ago)
```

which produces this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "contacts" ON "contacts"."client_id" = "clients"."id" INNER JOIN "meetings" ON "meetings"."contact_id" = "contacts"."id" INNER JOIN "clients_users" ON "clients"."id" = "clients_users"."client_id" WHERE "clients_users"."user_id" = $1 AND "clients"."is_dormant" = $2 AND (meetings.actual_start_datetime <= '2016-12-31 20:29:08.972999') AND (NOT (meetings.actual_start_datetime > '2016-12-31 20:29:08.973484'))  ORDER BY "clients"."name" ASC  [["user_id", 1], ["is_dormant", "f"]]
```

But it seems to just ignore the `where.not('meetings.actual_start_datetime > ?', 30.days.ago)` clause. If I run the query without that clause, it returns the exact same result.

After many days of deliberating, it seems the easiest way to do this is get all of the clients who have had a meeting 30 or more days ago, then subtract from that array the clients who have had a meeting in the last 30 days, eg:

```
user_clients.without_recent_meetings - user_clients.with_recent_meetings
```

Is there any way to do this in one query, as this way means having to run a complex query twice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
user.clients.where(is_dormant: false).joins(:meetings).distinct.where('meetings.actual_start_datetime <= ? AND clients.id not in (select m.client_id from meetings m where m.actual_start_datetime>?)', 30.days.ago)
```